# How can I get selected or editing row on Js-Grid?

Tags: jsgrid

I want to get just editing row validating field value with another field on the.
Bu it doesn't work.

```
 fields: [
    { name: "id", type: "text", align: "center", width: 10, editing: false, title:"ID"},
    { name: "total", type: "number", align: "center", width: 30, editing: false, title:"Total"},
    { name: "correct", type: "number", align: "center", width: 30,  
        validate: {validator: function(value, item) {
                        return value <= item.total;}, message: "Correct should be smaller or equal than Total"}
    },
    { type: "control", modeSwitchButton: false, editButton: true, deleteButton: false }]
```

can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I found some way like this:

```
var editing_row_field2;
....

onItemEditing: function(args) {
            editing_row_field2= args.item.field2; },

fields: [{ name: "field2", type: "number"},
         { name: "field1", type: "number",
             validate: { validator: function(value, item) {
                             return editing_row_field2 >= value; },
                         message: "FIELD1 should be smaller or equal than FIELD2." }
         },
         { type: "control", modeSwitchButton: false, editButton: true, deleteButton: false }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access other fields in current row using **item** argument from validator function

```
fields: [{ name: "field2", type: "number"},
         { name: "field1", type: "number",
             validate: { validator: function(value, item) {
                             return item.field2 >= value; },
                         message: "FIELD1 should be smaller or equal than FIELD2." }
         },
         { type: "control", modeSwitchButton: false, editButton: true, deleteButton: false }]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and inform you.